# paypal adaptive account creation

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have to use paypal adaptive account creation Rest api in one of my project. The java library is here https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-java. But when i try to integrate this using the following code

```
RequestEnvelope env = new RequestEnvelope();
env.setErrorLanguage("en_US");
NameType name = new NameType("John", "Lui");
AddressType address = new AddressType("Main St", "US");
String preferredLanguageCode ="en_US";            
CreateAccountRequest createAccountRequest = new CreateAccountRequest(env,name, address, preferredLanguageCode);            
Map<String, String> customConfigurationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
customConfigurationMap.put("mode", "sandbox");            
customConfigurationMap.put("acct1.UserName", "protest348_api1.gmail.com");
customConfigurationMap.put("acct1.Password", "HD6X2RX38WE78NUW");
customConfigurationMap.put("acct1.Signature", "AOKE31.o6thw-ButmC4-x.YFN6U-AuGNMBPR0Dbd9hkDMfzgJ1Zcm7yo");
customConfigurationMap.put("acct1.AppId", "APP-80W284485P519543T");
customConfigurationMap.put("sandbox.EmailAddress", "anoop.pk.kumar@gmail.com");
AdaptiveAccountsService adaptiveAccountsService = new AdaptiveAccountsService(customConfigurationMap);            
CreateAccountResponse createAccountResponse = adaptiveAccountsService.createAccount(createAccountRequest,"development@zgmail.com");
log.info(createAccountResponse.getAccountId());
```

In the log i got an error like

```
Unable to generate Access Token com.paypal.exception.MissingCredentialException: Account for the username does not exists in the properties file
```

How can i resolve this issue. i have following the same thing there in the githhub. but i don't know whether i have added the username, password, and signature correctly. How can i overwrite my signature with the default one in the library file? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create (fake) users the for sandbox environment. You can do all at  https://developer.paypal.com/

- Please go to [PayPal developer](https://developer.paypal.com/) and log in.
- Then click on "Dashboard"
- Under "Sandbox" click on "Accounts" (or click
  [here](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)).
- In that page you can create users. Create some for buyers and some
  for sellers. There you can get the credentials for those users as well.

Comment: All that i have done. my doubt is how can i add this configuration on my code.

Comment: well. there should be a place where you should copy all the credential info (username, password, signature) of the buyer.
Isn't here? -> customConfigurationMap.put("acct1.UserName", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX");

Comment: I believe is in this Configuration.java file, no?

Comment: Yah i have edited the question by adding the real sandbox values. But still i am getting the error on the log "Account for the username does not exists in the properties file"

Comment: So the error does not come from PayPal. It seems that the exception is thrown here:
https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/paypal/core/CredentialManager.java
I guess you will have to debug why you have "credential == null"